# Relay on a Ryobi Electric Riding Lawnmower

Tags: relay

I have a Ryobi RY481111 electric riding lawnmower wherein the blades refuse to spin most of the time, they will work on occasion. The major parts, outside of the batteries, are the drive controller and two blade motor controllers. I've tested the controllers and they appear to be fine but it's the relay that is causing some angst.

The relay is as pictured below. The low current is 12V, high current is 48V. According to the diagnostic document, the testing instructions are as follows;

1. Power Mower On
2. Set DMM to "DC Volts"
3. Check for 12V on the small terminals (under the black caps)
4. Check for approximately 39+V on the large terminals (under the red caps)

Now. Powered on the 12V measures properly, but I get no voltage testing the large terminals. The relay does actuate (confirmed via sound, and visually with the top cap removed). However, if I test with the mower off, I do get a measurement from the high side (just over 39, if I remember)

My relay knowledge is rather rudimentary, so it has me confused. Thus, questions;

- Does this indicate a bad relay or something outside of the relay?
- Can I bypass the relay by connecting the high current terminals to see if that powers the blades of this mower? (Hopefully indicating that replacing the relay may work).
- While getting a new relay is relatively inexpensive ($100 or so), I don't want to waste money/time if it is unlikely to be the issue
- The red-black between the two low terminals contains a diode.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Unfortunately, Ryobi hasn't returned my questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While it could be the relay, I suggest you look at the safety switches first. Riding mowers have sensors to detect that you're in the seat before they will start. The switch itself, or the switch connections, can become intermittent due to corrosion (mower decks are wet, messy places); or the switch can simply need mechanical adjustment to reliably actuate from your weight.

The second possibility is the motor or motor connections. It's brushless, so it's not just a matter of a worn out brush.

If you still suspect the relay, you have to create a situation where you can test it repeatedly until the failure occurs, then measure voltages. That's difficult. You may have to add some temporary wires to allow test probes.

Finally, be careful, that battery can produce enough current to start a fire, and the motor with blades mounted is a real hazard.

Comment: I've checked all the lockouts and everything is good. I have shorted on the relay and it did not produce any different results.   I have had the motors working but it seems to be random. At one point, if I blew out the top of the deck with a compressor, they would start. Another was disconnecting one of the motors, the other would start, then reconnecting both worked. Driving it around has actually gotten the blades to work. All point to a bad connection but I can't see one, jiggling the wires does not help.

Comment: @Toonces Sounds like you’ve ruled out the relay as the problem. I think it will take more extensive testing to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you include a picture of the wiring on the relay with your testing method (where exactly do you place voltmeter leads). 
It is hard to tell whether the relay is bad or whether you have placed voltmeter probes in the wrong place. It could also be that your motor is bad. 
There should be no problem shorting the relay contacts to see whether it works.

Comment: Neither of the motors spins (one for each blade). I have some documentation that I've been following. I'm fairly certain that I have properly used the multimeter to test the right connections. The low current at the front of the relay, the high current at the back of the relay. Front reads fine. 12V when mower is on, 0V when mower is off. High current is 39V when off, 0V when on. If I disconnect on of the high current leads from its post, it reads 48 whether the mower is off or it is on. Shorting made no difference. The relay is properly closing the connection.

Comment: OK, that sounds right. So, it's likely the motor, or possibly something else. You're losing 9 volts through the motor and something else with very little current going through, indicating a poor contact or another faulty component (but which?).